# Solve a complex equation with

Tags: complex-numbers

The equation is $z^2 = 1 + i$. I solved this equation by replacing z by x + iy and then simplifying everything that can be. Then I got my z1 & z2 by using a system. However, although my solution seems correct, in the handbook they solved the problem using $e$ and got the following solution:
$$
2^{1/4} e^{i \frac{\pi}{8}} \quad \text{and} \quad 2^{1/4} e^{i \frac{9\pi}{8}}
$$

It isn't explained anywhere, so I'm kinda stuck on how they solved it this way. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcFLZ.jpg)

Comment: It would help if you show what you have done.

Comment: From the solution, you already see that it's easier to write $z=re^{i\theta}$. Also squaring with this is very easy. You only need to write $1+i$ in this form after that.

Comment: @MattiP. I appreciate the help, I assume you can get r & θ . by determining the polar equation?

Comment: Well, yeah, basically you just need to visualize the point $1+i$ on the plane and write the polar form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

They simply used the *exponential form* of a complex number: any $z=x+iy\in\mathbf C$ can be written as
$$z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta},\quad\text{ where }\; r=|z|\;\text{ and }\;\mathrm e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta.$$ The *argument* of $z$, $\theta$, is the polar angle of the image of $z$ in the Argand-Cauchy plane, defined modulo $2\pi$.

We have $\;1+i=\sqrt2\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}$, so the equation $z^2=1+i$ is equivalent to
$$r^2\mathrm e^{2i\theta}=\sqrt2\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}\iff\begin{cases}r^2=\sqrt 2,\\2\theta\equiv\frac\pi 4\mod 2\pi.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This helped a lot, appreciate it!